# Get the location of the network in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

Something come up at my work place last week that we are handling the date fields based on `UTC` and convert them to `local time zones` respectively. I was thinking to get the network address that will be dynamically pass through `SQL Server` and get the location of the user login and we can accurately know the `time zone` based on location.

**Note:**
  The user is employee in Baltimore office but if he has to go to another office location in Texas then I should known based on network change and location the `local time zone`.

Any ideas are welcome.....

Thanks

Comment: Changing to local time should be done on the client, based on the local time-zone set at the OS level. All times in and out of the database should be in UTC.

Comment: I wanted to know the network location so I can access the local time based on it. Yes, you are right that all the time in Database are stored as UTC.